# Nginx restrict access to files with certain name

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403

How to restrict access to files ending like that "-1000.jpg", for example:

```
folder1/aaa-1000.jpg
folder2/bb-1000.jpg
folder3/ccccc-1000.jpg
```

I tried :

```
location ~* (\-1000\.jpg)$ {
        return 403;
}
```

No success files ending with "-1000.jpg" are still accessible.

Comment: Try this `location ~ \-1000\.jpg$`

Comment: No they are still accessible. Even if I do `location ~ .jpg$ {
                return 403;
        }` Whatever I do .jpg files are accessible.

Comment: Ok, got it. It was not working because of this which was just before        `location ~* .(ico|jpg|png|gif|jpeg|css|swf|js|woff)$ {
                access_log off;
                expires 1M;
                add_header Cache-Control private;
        }`